# Is $\sqrt{1-\tan^2(x)}$ continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I think how $\sqrt{x}$ is continuous in $[0,\infty) $ then  $\sqrt{1-\tan^2(x)}$ is continuous when $1-\tan^2(x)\geq0$ but wolfram says that is not continuous so I am confused

Comment: The limit for the function at $\pi/2$ does not exists so function $\sqrt{1-tan^{2}(x)}$ is not continuous for $f(x)\geq 0$

Comment: What about $x=\pi/2$?

Comment: What exactly did you input to WA? The function is continuous at every point where it is defined (i.e., at every $x$ such that $1-\tan^2(x) \ge 0$), as you said.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common misconception about continuity and the statement needs to be clearly defined. **On its domain,** the function $f(x) = \sqrt{1-\tan^2(x)}$ is continuous. No more than that.

By definition of continuity, it does not make sense to ask whether a function is continuous in points where it is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

tanx is not defined at odd multiples of π/2 so the function would also be not defined at those points. Hence the function would not be continuous at odd multiples of π/2.

Comment: I strongly disagree: As $\tan$ isn't defined at $x=\pi/2$ the  sequence of words and symbols: $$\text{$\tan$ is not continuous at $x=\pi/2$.}$$  isn't a statement at all.

Comment: @Michael Hoppe: I don't think mathematics should be abused to play silly word games.

Comment: @M.Wind  I don't get you.  Where a function is undefined it can't possibly have any properties.

Comment: @Giorgio Zorzi detto Giorgione I believe "continuous" depends on the context and how it is defined in that context. It is not necessarily on the domain. In many texts, "continuous"  without mentioning a domain of continuity refers to the whole space. Nevertheless you have a point in that the question should be clear.